# Box upload files using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I try to upload a file using Box.com API from https://gist.github.com/seanrose/5570650.

I received the following error:

> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

What can I do? How can I upload files to Box.com using AJAX?

Comment: Do you have access to your server header information?

Comment: i don't understand, can you explain me why i need to have an access to the server header?

Comment: to allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: in that case the Server which need to give me a permission is the BOX, or maybe is there another option that i can get a permission?

Comment: You can request CORS headers be added to your Box integration. It's an email to api@box.com to get the URL added.  Note that Box will not allow wildcards in the CORS header.

Comment: Any update?  Did you try getting a CORS exception added for your service?

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the [Box Developer Docs](https://docs.box.com/reference#api-docs-directory) under the topic CORS. You need to visit your Box Application Configuration page and add the comma separated list of addresses/IPs to the CORS Allowed Origins field. For example:

[image]
    http://127.0.0.1,http://localhost,http://localhost:3000,http://10.0.1.2,http://0.0.0.0,https://example.com